# Assistance query change membergroup

Tags: control-panel, member-management, query-module

I am unfamiliair with the Query module and I hope someone here could guide me.

In a Template I want to change the group_id of a chosen member (member_id in stash snippet) from 13 to 14. The template is only accessable for super-admins.

Reason for that is that I want an editor of that site to be able to do this, but I do not want them to access the full member-section in the CP. (Too complicated)

Is this possible?

Really thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query module can only be used for data lookups, not for modifying the DB. You either have to use PHP in your template or, much better, write a small add on - this can probably best be done with a plug-in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not trust myself doing this safely. So we'll have to look for a developer that can do this for us....

Comment: It's not a big job - I'll do it if you buy me a beer - careful - I have expensive taste in beer - email me if interested.

Comment: Thanx you-got-mail sir.